# Set up wake-on-lan for mac os x via Actiontec T1200H Router: Ports 7 and 9 are closed

Tags: macos, port, port-forwarding, wake-on-lan

I've got two macs connected to home wireless network via Actiontec T1200H Router.

Both macs support Wake on Wireless (in **About this Mac-->System Report-->Network-->Wi-fi-->Wake On Wireless:   Supported** )

Both machines have `"Wake for network access"` checked in **System Preferences --> Energy Saver** which also means that both support WoL via WiFi (read it from here: https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201960).

Both running OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite. Port forwarding in router web interface (I'm not sure if I've done a correct):

```
LAN IP Address: 192.168.1.64 # macbookpro which is supposed to get WoL packet
  External (WAN) Start Port:  9
  External (WAN) End Port:  9
  Internal (LAN) Start Port:  9
  Internal (LAN) End Port:  9
  Protocol:  UDP
```

And the same for port 7.

I'm trying to wake up my MacBookPro 15" Mid 2010 **(laptop connected to power adaptor and the built-in display is open)** sending pakets from macpro with this command:

```
$ wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.64 -p 9 g8:bc:c9:d4:b0:ee
Sending magic packet to 192.168.1.64:9 with g8:bc:c9:d4:b0:ee
```

So it doesn't work, and when I scan port 9 nmap says it's closed:

```
$ sudo nmap -sU -p 7,9 192.168.1.64
...
PORT  STATE  SERVICE
7/udp closed echo
9/udp closed discard
```

I'm checking if the mac address is correct using `arp -a` and WakeOnLan GUI from `homebrew cask`. They show identical addresses so I believe this is the correct address of wifi interface which are the computers connected through (en1-for macbookpro, en2-for macpro).

It also doesn't work for my new mac pro (Late 2013).

So what am I doing wrong? Should it be like that or do I need to somehow open those ports? Am I missing anything? Please help.

Comment: Not an answer but... you may like to use the `fing` app on an iPhone/iPad to generate Wake-on-LAN packets very simply.

Comment: Lol, is it an ad?

Comment: No, it's a great free tool - I use it all the while to debug networks and wake up NAS backup targets.

Comment: Cool! I knew about it. I use Scany, but it's not free. Thanx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

NAT port mapping is not necessary for Wake on Wireless LAN unless the machine sending the wake packet is on the public (WAN, Internet) side of the NAT. If I understand your first line correctly, both of your Macs are connected via Wi-Fi to your ActionTec T1200H. So they're on the same (wireless) Ethernet LAN.

Following the instructions in that support article you linked to, did you verify in System Information (not Energy Saver) on the MacBook Pro that you see "Wake On Wireless: Supported"?

Did you check that `g8:bc:c9:d4:b0:ee` is the correct MAC address for the Wi-Fi interface of your MacBook Pro?

It might be helpful to know the exact Model Identifier (e.g. "MacBookPro11,3") of your model of MacBook Pro. For the last couple of years, Macs have had wireless cards with enough built-in smarts to handle WPA/WPA2 group key rotation and other things necessary to keep associated to a Wi-Fi network and keep Bonjour services advertised on the network while the rest of the system sleeps. These support Wake on Wireless LAN with any brand of 802.11 AP (wireless router). However, there were earlier models of Macs with less-sophisticated wireless cards that supported Wake on Wireless LAN **only** when associated to an Apple AirPort [Extreme, Express, Time Capsule] base station. If your machine is old enough to fall into that category, you'll never be able to get Wake on Wireless LAN to work with your ActionTec router.

Also, did you notice this caveat from the support article?

> Portable Macs with Wake on Demand enabled will only perform Wake on Demand functions when they are connected to a power adaptor and either the built-in display is open or an external display is attached.

Do you have your MacBook Pro connected to a power adapter and either have the lid open or an external display connected?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I've done all changes to the explanation as you've asked. Seems like everything should work or I've missed something again(((

Comment: @Andrew BTW, did you make up that MAC address in order to keep your MacBook Pro's real MAC address private? I ask because if you thought that was your real MAC address, you've made a mistake, because 'g' is not a valid hexadecimal digit.

Comment: @Andrew Also, since you're on the same LAN, you don't need the `-i $IPADDRESS` argument to `wakeonlan`, and in fact that could cause it to break if the sending machine does not have a static ARP mapping for the target machine. Leave that part out so your packet is sent to the IPv4 limited broadcast address.

Comment: well of course I did make it up - 'g' shows that. I'm using the real one. And it didn't work without `-i $IPADDRESS`. But when I do this I get: `Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with $MACADDRESS`

Comment: @Andrew I think your 2010 MacBook Pro is too old to handle group key rotation in the wireless card (too old to handle Wake on Wireless with a third-party AP, at least if the AP has WPA or WPA2 enabled). Try waking the 2013 Mac Pro again, this time without the `-i $IPADDRESS`.

Comment: That's what I've tried and it didn't work... I also changed the `LAN IP Address` to macpro's in web interface of router. Still doesn't work (((

Comment: Well what IP address do I need to write in web interface for port forwarding? Broadcast? The router's one? or the endpoint one's?