# PF: Can't open port on OS X

Tags: firewall, port, wake-on-lan, pf

Have troubles opening the port 9 on os x 10.10.3 yousemite using pf firewall. I want to do this for being able to get wake-on-lan packets to this port. I assume that for WoL to work the port (on the machine to be awaken) should be opened for UDP packets (Please correct me if I'm not right)

Having this in **/etc/pf.conf**:

```
# Open port 9 for UDP on all interfaces
pass in proto udp from any to any port 9 keep state
```

Restarting the pf with this command:

```
sudo /sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

But getting `port closed` when I do:

```
sudo nmap -sU -p 9 localhost
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000085s latency).
PORT  STATE  SERVICE VERSION
9/udp closed discard
```

I've tried to create custom **/etc/pf_cust.conf:**

```
anchor "pf.rules"
load anchor "pf.rules" from "/etc/pf.anchors/pf.rules"
```

and use custom ruleset **/etc/pf.anchors/pf.rules:**

```
# Open port 9 for UDP on all interfaces
pass in proto udp from any to any port 9 keep state
```

using: `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf_cust.conf`
But nmap shows it still closed and wake on lan doesn't work (MacPro is relatively new (2013), has Wake On Wireless: Supported, and "Wake for network access" checked in System Preferences --> Energy Saver).

Please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this Mac Pro acting as a network middlebox of some sort (router/gateway/NAT/bridge)? Or is it the endpoint that you're trying to wake?

If it's the endpoint you're trying to wake, you don't need the port open. Wake on LAN packets work at the link layer. The Ethernet (or Wi-Fi) chip looks for the magic pattern (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff followed by 16 copies of the interface's hardware MAC address) in every packet it receives. It doesn't even pay attention to anything else in the packet, so it has no idea if the packet is even an IP packet or not, or what TCP or UDP port it's addressed to.

When it comes to WoL magic packets, worrying about IP addresses and ports is only necessary if you're trying to send the packet from a different part of the Internet, and you need to figure out a way to get it through routers and firewalls and NAT gateways. But once it's hit the *Ethernet hardware* of the target host that needs to wake, it's done its job and caused the wake. It makes no difference at all if the host OS, once awake, decides to reject the packet, because by then, the host is awake, so the job is done.

Comment: Hi Spiff! We were disscussing the topic before:http://superuser.com/questions/925494/set-up-wake-on-lan-for-mac-os-x-via-actiontec-t1200h-router-ports-7-and-9-are-c I'm still trying to get wol to work in my wi-fi network... And so I absolutely run out of ideas, that's why I've tried again and asked this question((( the main question in the link.

Comment: The Mac Pro acting as the endpoint I'm trying to wake

Comment: What IP address do I need to write in web interface for port forwarding? Broadcast? The router's one? or the endpoint one's? Should the port 9 of the router be open?

Comment: @Andrew From your other Question, isn't the machine sending the wake packet on the same LAN as the machine being waked? If so, you (still) don't need to worry about IP addresses and ports.

Comment: I see. The machine is also in the local network. but t doesn't work when it should work... Basically what I've done for wake on lan is just checked the "Wake for network access" on all machines and installed the wakeonlan from homebrew - and sending wol packets to the mac address of macpro. may I forget anything? I've already tried to connect my macpro to router via ethernet - still doesn't work(((